# how to change Bootstrap 4 layout to remove spaces and make it responsive

Tags: layout, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, space

I am currently working on a project of making a web.But after using bootstrap I got some error in spaces in between the pictures its not also responsive in web as well as in app. 
The content is divided into two category Y and C the Y is fine in its space the problem is coming from C section.The category label is also not responsive .If you can fix the error please provide me with a layout which is perfect in web and app using bootstrap.

Thanks in advance!

```
<div class=" secondbtn" style="align-items: center;">
    <h4>The Y category</h4>
</div>


        <div class="filtr-container galleryContainer d">
            <!-- item -->


           <div class="col-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filtr-item thumbnail" data-category="Malavian,Y" data-sort="">
                <img src="images/animals/animals (1).jpg" alt="">

                <span class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 item-desc" style="position: initial;">Malavian  Cichlids</span>
            </div>

        <div class="col-4 col-md-3  col-lg-3 filtr-item thumbnail" data-category="Malavian,Tanganyikan,C" data-sort="cat">
            <img src="images/animals/animals (4).jpg" alt="">
            <span class="item-desc" style="position: initial;">plecos</span>
        </div>




</div>
        <div class="second" >
                <h4><span>The C category</span></h4>
            </div>


    <section class="container-fluid ">
        <div class="layout_M filtr-container galleryContainer d">

            <div class="col-4 col-md-3 col-lg-4 filtr-item thumbnail" data-category="Malavian,C" data-sort="cat">

                <img src="images/animals/animals (4).jpg" alt="">
                <span class="item-desc" style="position: initial;" >Barbs</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-4 col-md-3 col-lg-4 filtr-item thumbnail" data-category="Malavian,C" data-sort="dog">
                <img src="images/animals/animals (5).jpg" alt="">
                <span class="item-desc">Cory Cats</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-4 col-md-3 col-lg-4 filtr-item thumbnail" data-category="Malavian,C" data-sort="dog">
                <img src="images/animals/animals (5).jpg" alt="">
                <span class="item-desc">Freshwater Plants</span>
            </div>

</div>
</section>

    </div>
</div>
```

[image: The space bellow C category!]

Answer (score 0):

To make t responsive try to wrap your columns in a div with class name row.

Comment: still got no changes!!

Comment: also remove some of the col classes. only keep col-md-3. Some of the column classes are conflicting each other